# Matching only a single standalone letter

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches only a *single standalone* letter only, such as `a`,`C`,`f`,`G`, but, NOT `abc` or `de` for instance.

I tried `[a-zA-z]`, but all of the above match.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Maybe something like `/(?:^|[^a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])(?![a-zA-Z])/`?

Comment: This could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521851.

Comment: Are you trying to find a single character in a sentence, or strings that consist of only a single letter? Please provide sample input and your expected output.

Comment: I agree with @theTinMan because something like `/(?=\b([a-z]{1})\b)/i` [Example](http://rubular.com/r/5iAm9ajSD1) might make more sense too just depends on what you are expecting to get out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z]$
```

Add `^$` or anchors to limit match to just one character.

or

```
(?:^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z]))[a-zA-Z](?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

Comment: could even go with case-insensitivity `^[a-z]$/i` [Example](http://rubular.com/r/KAUCnw6nb0). BTW `^` and `$` are start and end of line so depending on context `\A` and `\z` might be better.

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah a smarter way :)

Comment: The OP didn't specify whether these are single letter strings or whether the string contains words and single letters. Until that's defined trying to answer is shooting in the dark. Using `^` or `\A` and `$` or `\z` or `\Z` will only work if the question is for single character strings.

Comment: @theTinMan you are correct but since this already had upvotes thought I would post my 2 cents on the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, depending on your content. This could work:

```
[^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]
```

Or there's a regex code for that, the \b:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]\b
```

which is more useful since it allows matches at the start and end of a line.

Comment: `\b` wont be of much help if string is like `3a`

Comment: @vks, the OP said "single standalone letter only".

Comment: `\b[a-zA-Z]\b` is the better way to look for a stand-alone character. But the question remains whether the OP wants single-letter strings or strings of words and single letters mixed.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `[a-zA-z]` matches not only letters but also matches `[`, `]`, `\`, `^`, `_` and `` ` ``. Moreover, it has no anchors and thus will match both `a` and `t` in `at`.

[image]

You can make use of the [POSIX bracket expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) `alpha` to match a single letter substring together with a [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
puts 'a,C,f,G, but, NOT abc de'.scan(/\b[[:alpha:]]\b/)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/WQnPmR)

Output:

```
a
C
f
G
```

Comment: I like the POSIX, but `[a-zA-z]` is a typo; should be `[a-zA-Z]` which does not match  [, ], \, ^, _ and ` : `"[]\^_" =~ /[a-zA-Z]/` returns nil.

Comment: @steenslag: typos in regex are expensive, and very misleading in SO questions. It was not mentioned in the comments that it was a typo, thus, I added this to my answer.